# Change of ng-model value on ng-click

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, angularjs-ng-model

I have a div in which i have four radio options in ng-repeat, my problem is when i click on the button the div with list class should be duplicated and the ng-model should change lets say if it is having value 'breakfast.favourite' after the click it should become 'breakfast.favourite1' for the duplicated div

```
<div class="main" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">    
<div class="list">
    <label class="item item-radio" ng-repeat="breakfastRecipe in breakfastRecipes" for="{{breakfastRecipe.name}}" ng-click="closeModal()">
        <input type="radio" ng-model="breakfast.favourite" ng-value="breakfastRecipe.name" id="{{'breakfast'+breakfastRecipe.id}}" name="boolean" />

    </label><br />
    {{breakfast.favourite}}
</div>
<button>Add Another</button>
```

here is my controller

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
$scope.breakfastRecipes = [{id : 1, name : 'BreakfastRecipe1'},{id : 2, name : 'BreakfastRecipe2'},{id : 3, name : 'BreakfastRecipe3'},{id : 4, name : 'BreakfastRecipe4'}];
$scope.breakfast=[];
}]);
```

Help me out on this one

http://jsfiddle.net/hari_k/sjvrau3a/8/

Comment: Append what? ng-model changed to what?

Comment: It seems working, what's the problem?

Comment: Please provide more details when asking questions. We know nothing about your project. Provide a proper problem statement and expected behaviors

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to achieve this?

http://jsfiddle.net/TheRodeo/taujuuq2/3/

```
<button ng-click="addItem()">Add Another</button>
<div>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="breakfastItem in breakfast  track by $index">{{breakfastItem}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>


$scope.addItem = function()
{
    $scope.breakfast.push($scope.breakfast.favourite);
}
```

Comment: [upvoted] Although the OP didn't accept it. It ended a long enduring headache I was having.